# bangla encoding in Python - UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

How do i store the content "আপনার" as UTF-8 "আপনার"? I have tried the following:

```
>>> content = "আপনার"
>>> content
'\xe0\xa6\x86\xe0\xa6\xaa\xe0\xa6\xa8\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\xb0'
```

---

```
>>> content = "আপনার".encode("UTF-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

```
>>> content = "আপনার".decode("UTF-8")
>>> content
u'\u0986\u09aa\u09a8\u09be\u09b0'
```

Answer (score 2):

The second one works, but you have to use `print content` instead of `content`:

```
>>> content = "আপনার".decode("UTF-8")
>>> print content
আপনার
```

## `__str__` and `__repr__`

This is the difference between a `str` and `__repr__` formats of an object. The first is meant to be human-readable, the second is meant to expose internals and be unique to the object. You can read more in [Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python).

### String representation

```
>>> print unicode(content)
আপনার
```

### `__repr__` representation

```
>>> print content.__repr__()
u'\u0986\u09aa\u09a8\u09be\u09b0'
```

Comment: so if i were to store this content in mongoDB and were to expose it for 3rd party apps via a REST API, will it show inconsistency?

Comment: Be consistent with with the representation you send and receive from and to mongo, and you'll be fine. I think that sending a `unicode` object - which you have in hand - is sufficient.